# nginx and proxy_pass - send Connection: close headers

Tags: http, nginx

nginx seems to be replacing the `Connection: close` header that upstream is sending, and replacing it with a `Connection: keep-alive` header. Is there any way I can override it?

```
http {
  upstream main {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
  server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://main;
    }
    location /find {
      proxy_pass http://main;
      proxy_buffering off;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `keepalive_requests 0;` convinced nginx to send `Connection: close`.

Comment: Unsatisfactory. This directive can only take a literal number, not a variable. I need to be able to decide whether to close the connection or not on a per-request basis, possibly after examining upstream response with Lua.

Answer (score 2):

The Connection header is specific to a connection.

From the HTTP/1.1 spec,

> The Connection general-header field allows the sender to specify options that are desired for that particular connection and MUST NOT be communicated by proxies over further connections.

So what nginx sends is independent of what's being sent from upstream and must be.  Here are some options:

keepalive_requests 0 works if you never want connections reused.

keepalive_disable ua works for a particular user agent.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010681/5269883) works an ip.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `fastcgi_finish_request()` if you're using PHP-FPM or PHP FastCGI:

> This feature allows you to speed up implementation of some php
>   queries. Acceleration is possible when there are actions in the
>   process of script execution that do not affect server response. For
>   example, saving the session in memcached can occur after the page has
>   been formed and passed to a web server. fastcgi_finish_request() is a
>   php feature, that stops the response output. Web server immediately
>   starts to transfer response “slowly and sadly” to the client, and php
>   at the same time can do a lot of useful things in the context of a
>   query, such as saving the session, converting the downloaded video,
>   handling all kinds of statistics, etc.

http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Features#fastcgi_finish_request.28.29

Answer (score 0):

Disabling keepalive on a secure server can increase the server load, check the "HTTPS server optimization" session on this document..
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

I may want to set a small keepalive_requests value and set an keepalive_requests also

Answer (score 0):

You can patch `NGINX`. Take `FastCGI` for example, add

```
if (strcmp((char *)h->key.data, "Connection") == 0 && strcmp((char *)h->value.data, "close") == 0) {
     ngx_log_debug0(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, r->connection->log, 0, "Set Connection: close");
     r->keepalive = 0;
}
```

in  `src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c` line 1977, right after the header parser.