# Force nginx to close connection instantly

Tags: php, javascript, nginx

How do I let nginx close the tcp connection instantly after the request is fulfilled?

Comment: Can't you just send a `Connection: close` header?

Comment: By the looks of it in some configs nginx does not close connection but sends response header back with Connection: close as it received it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just found the solution:

```
location /ip/ {
    keepalive_timeout 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection is maintained between the server and the browser thanks to the Keep Alive requests exchanged between them.

You can disable the Keep Alive behavior for a particular user agent: see [the *nginx* manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_disable)

```
keepalive_disable ua
```

You can probably trick your browser to have a given user agent, having the keep alive cut only for your particular needs.

Comment: It looks like its not possible to change the user agent with an `XMLHTTPRequest`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5862744/1485952

Comment: This is not a neat solution because you cannot use arbitrary user-agent strings for this trick.